# how to detect click on toolbar Grip in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using **toolbar's in WPF**. Now I want to detect click on toolbar when I clicked on **Grip of toolbar only**. How can i do this ? any Suggestion ?

Comment: some kind of drag and drop

Comment: yeah Just Drag a toolbar from one place to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to define a preview mouse down handler for the toolbar...

```
        <ToolBar Name="toolBar1"  ToolBarTray.IsLocked="False"  PreviewMouseDown="toolBar1_PreviewMouseDown" >
            <Menu ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded">
                <MenuItem Header="File" />
                <MenuItem Header="New" />
            </Menu>
        </ToolBar>
```

Then in the handler, do a hit test to determine if you are over the Thumb which is the control which implements the grip...

```
    private void toolBar1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(toolBar1);
            IInputElement ie = toolBar1.InputHitTest(p);
            Thumb t = GetParent<Thumb>(ie as DependencyObject);
            if(t != null)
            {
                // we have clicked on the grip...
            }

        }

    }
    private T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : class
    {
        while (d != null && !(d is T))
        {
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
        }
        return d as T;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked :)

Comment: can u please tell me the Dependency Object is Just Grip in toolbar ?

Comment: A dependency object is a very basic element of MVVM.  A Grip is a dependency object as are many, many other things.

Comment: Then why it Returns Grip only ?

Comment: It only returns Grip if the mouse is over the grip.  The code searches up the visual tree to find the Grip.  If you are over some other part of the toolbar, the Grip will not be found in the visual tree hierarchy and null will be returned.

Comment: yeah if i am not wrong it return dependency object and in toolbar it has only dependency object which is Grip . Am i right ?

Comment: That is generally correct.  The controls that are commonly added to the toolbar (button, menu, combobox, etc) do not have grips.  However it is possible that some other control has a grip element and so you will find that control instead of the toolbar grip.  So to protect against this case you would need to do some additional checks.  Not worth it in my view.

Comment: Thanks for the Help